# Azure cloud service definition problems

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, definition, application-pool

I have a cloud service which was running fine for a while after upgrading to Azure 2.0 SDK. It has now mysteriously stopped working. I am getting this in the Azure machines event log.

```
The application '/' belonging to site '19369254' has an invalid
AppPoolId 'ddcc23fe-8eee-4412-a4dd-56b50e18d9f2' set.  
Therefore, the application will be ignored.
```

Followed by :

```
Site 19369254 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is 
invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the 
root application is invalid.
```

and :

```
 A process serving application pool 'ddcc23fe-8eee-4412-a4dd-56b50e18d9f2'
 terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3696'. 
 The process exit code was '0x103'.
```

My service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="SMEEDI.Cloud" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
<WebRole name="SMEEDI.Portal" enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"></Task>
</Startup>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="DiagnosticsConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="DataConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="BaseUrl" />
  <Setting name="DatabaseConnectionString" />
  <Setting name="Environment" />
</ConfigurationSettings>

<Sites>
  <Site name="Smeedi_WebRole" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\SMEEDI.Portal">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
</WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

1. How could this suddenly stop working?
2. What is wrong with the service definition?

Comment: Try remoting into the server and doing this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735307(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Also... there were breaking changes to the physicalDirectory attribute on the <Site>.  I don't know if that matters here, but just another lead.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving should have nothing to do with the CSDEF file. It appears to be an issue with the configuration of IIS on the Azure instance.
 
You can try to reimage the instance from the Azure portal or log into the instance to do further troubleshooting. If you choose to remote in, I would examine the IIS configuration, specifically the Application Pools and virtual directories, especially the path since you are changing it in the CSDEF. 
Azure should take care of that configuration on its own, which is why reimage or delete and redeploy may be a better first step.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I have done multiple builds/deployments.. It has been working as is for weeks. I will check the path though, thanks for the input.